# How to enable Screenreader "Browse Mode" in a custom Application?

Tags: wpf, windows, screen-readers, nvda

Screen readers like [NVDA](https://www.nvaccess.org/download/) implement two modes of operation: [Browse Mode and Focus Mode](https://www.accessibility-developer-guide.com/knowledge/screen-readers/desktop/browse-focus-modes/).

- Browse Mode is for reading a website/document/application. The screen reader will read all visible contents.
- To interact with the website/document/application, Focus Mode offers some advantages: only the interactive content parts are read. In a website, this would mean that links, buttons, forms and navigation are read, but normal text is not read.

In NVDA, you can usually switch between Browse and Focus mode with Insert+Space, which is then confirmed by a sound. This works in most applications: Browsers, Windows Explorer, Skype, VS Code.

However, in my own WPF application (which e.g. has accessibility labels), when I press Insert+Space, nothing happens. NVDA seems to always be in Focus Mode, and there is no Browse Mode.

Intuitively this makes sense, because for Browse Mode, the screenreader needs to "know" what elements it should read, and in what order.

I have no clue where to begin implementing it. Is this a common WPF problem? Is it a problem of NVDA, which somehow needs to know that the application is capable of Browse Mode?

Comment: This browse vs focus modes seems to be specific to screen reader. I'm not aware of anything like that in UI Automation / Accessibility. I've tried NVDA but not sure how to switch from one mode to another, it doesn't seem to change the overall behavior. Can you detail what it does, and how to make sure it's on/off?

Comment: On Windows, you normally switch with Insert+Space. You should hear an audible confirmation for the mode switch. For details about what it does, see [here](https://www.accessibility-developer-guide.com/knowledge/screen-readers/desktop/browse-focus-modes/).

Comment: Looking at NVDA source (https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda), it doesn't seem to be anything "magic", and from what I understand reading the doc, it's really for "browsers" *"Reading through a website by moving the screen reader's cursor ... is called "browse" mode"*, or it's hardcoded for some very well-known apps https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/tree/master/source/virtualBuffers https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/tree/master/source/NVDAObjects/UIA. Add to that WPF doesn't support natively setting Aria properties. IMHO you should create an issue in the NVDA repo and ask.

Comment: @SimonMourier I have opened an issue / discussion there, but it has not received much attention: https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/discussions/13448. Please have a look at the answer by slugolicious: looking at the list of applications that support Browse Mode, there seems to be a pattern, but the pattern is not very clear (Windows Settings app has static text, but there is no Browse Mode).

Comment: All accessibility tools mentioned use UI Automation which has no concept such as "browse mode" vs "focus mode". AFAIK, the pattern is really like I said: all apps are either browsers or support is hardcoded (note that VS Code is a browser too, it uses Electron which hosts Chromium). In your issue you mention a browser hosted in a Windows app, and this seems to support NVDA browse mode fine with WPF or Winforms and an embedded (IE) WebBrowser.

Comment: @SimonMourier The problem is, we have a (WPF) app which has both static text in it, which is available in accessibility, and an embedded browser control (CEF). But screen readers do not offer Browse Mode on our app. To resolve this issue, I thought we first need to know how screen readers decide whether an app supports Browse Mode.

Comment: Not sure CEFSharp (or is it CEF?) https://gitter.im/cefsharp/CefSharp?at=5ee5a05429d8bc28f9f5b31b look for NVDA) is supported. I've tried it and contrary to standard WPF-embedded webbrowser, it doesn't seem to work. From an UIA standpoint, it's just an image so there's no way accessibility tools can "understand" it. Some info for NVDA is here: https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/blob/master/devDocs/technicalDesignOverview.md#browse-mode-documents and https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/tree/master/nvdaHelper#nvda-helper

Comment: Like I said, there's no magic bullet. Browse mode first requires the target app to be scanned and a "virtualbuffer" be built for it (with concepts such as headings, text, etc.). There are even cases when NVDA injects dll into target process (like Word) to enhance all this. What you can do is build an addon/extension to NVDA with python to enable NVDA to see your app as you want. There's no such example on the NVDA site, for here's once: https://github.com/derekriemer/nvda-notepadPlusPlus (note it doesn't have browse mode)

Comment: @SimonMourier: you say "there's no way accessibility tools can understand it". This does not seem true, as NVDA correctly reads the accessibility text of the focused web element inside of the browser control. However, it only works for focused elements. Static text is not read. The behavior seems to be exactly Focus Mode: focused elements are read, but static text not. That's why I'm asking about Browse mode.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/tree/master/CefSharp.Wpf.Example I don't see NVDA announcing anything in the browser part, focused or not. I've tried a more simple example and it's the same, while it works fine with WPF's WebBrowser https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.webbrowser because MSHTML is well-known by NVDA https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/blob/master/source/virtualBuffers/MSHTML.py and https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/blob/master/source/NVDAObjects/IAccessible/MSHTML.py

Comment: @SimonMourier sorry should have said, we are using CEF, but not the WPF component. I don't know why, but we are using the CEF browser control for WinForms (`ChromiumHostControl`), which is then embedded in the WPF app via a `WindowsFormsHost`. So, if you run the `CefSharp.WinForms.Example`, you will see that NVDA indeed reads all interactive elements. Non-interactive elements are read only if the mouse is hovered over them, so we need a Browse Mode, which lets the user browse through the text contents of the page.

Comment: Right, and that just confirms what I said. In this Winforms sample, the automation tree is indeed present (it's not one big image or raw pane like it is with WPF CefSharp) see here: https://i.imgur.com/cVWzCE2.png that's why NVDA is capable of announcing what's under the cursor, focus, etc. But still, that has nothing to do with so-called "focus mode" vs "browser mode" which are screenreaders-specific concepts.

Comment: @SimonMourier yes, but that's exactly my question: what are the details of the screen-reader concept of "Browse Mode" and "Focus Mode"? That's the thing I want to understand. You said "Browse mode first requires the target app to be scanned and a "virtualbuffer" be built for it (with concepts such as headings, text, etc.)". The webpage inside the CEF browser inside my app has all those things. Why does NVDA still treat it different from all the other browser-like apps?

Comment: @SimonMourier maybe the question title was misleading: I just changed it from "How to implement..." to "How to enable..."

Comment: Unless you have a better answer from NVDA authors, the answer to the question is simple: you must change NVDA or better write an NVDA extension, there's nothing you can do from your app side. Simple answer, but doesn't mean work is simple, you must dive into NVDA code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems this is the way NVDA detects accessibility of an application:

> Normally, NVDA uses the IAccessible2 API to get accessibility information from Chrome. With this embedded version of Chrome, NVDA seems to be unable to query the IAccessible2 interfaces and falls back to plain IAccessible/MSAA. I've seen this in embeded Chrome versions in Qt as well. Pretty sure it is a problem in the embedded version of Chrome.

Source: https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/13493

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you built your application with the accessibility compiler option turned off?  Here are a few things you can check:

- [Accessibility switches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/whats-new-in-accessibility#accessibility-switches) in .NET
- Example of [solving an accessibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/accessibility-tools-docs/items/wpf/control_iscontrolelement) issue in .NET
- Using [Accessibility Insights](https://accessibilityinsights.io/) to inspect accessibility properties in a WPF

If you run the built-in calculator app on Windows, it has the same problem as your app.  You're always in forms mode and <kbd>Ins</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> won't switch to browse mode.  However, there isn't really any "plain text" to read in the calculator app.  Every element is an interactive element.

However, the Settings app does have some plain text and it has the same problem too.  I can navigate to all the interactive elements but I can't get to the "Get even more out of Windows" text or the text underneath it.  Visually it looks like a heading followed by a paragraph but switching to NVDA browse mode doesn't work.

<kbd>[image: screenshot of settings app, text in upper right corner highlighted]</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your hints. Accessibility Insight seems to be helpful. Do you know how NVDA decides whether an app supports Browse and Focus Modes?

Comment: My guess is that NVDA is **not** deciding that. It’s usually controlled by what the app surfaces to the accessibility tree. But you can always check for an NVDA community forum on https://www.nvaccess.org/

Comment: As I suspected, the JAWS screen reader has the same issue.  You can't switch between modes in the Calculator or Settings app so this leans towards it being an application issue that it's not surfacing the right info to the application tree and not an NVDA decision.

Comment: I see, so my question really is, what accessibility info do I need to provide for the screenreaders to recognize the application as supporting "browse mode".

Comment: Yes, that’s probably a more accurate question. But I’m not a .net developer so I’ll have to bow out now.

Comment: Awarded you the bounty, because of missing other answers :-)